# How can I successfully have pagenotes (endnotes) with a reference to the page where they are set in the page they're printed but not viceversa?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, books, endnotes, pagenote

In practice, I want to have text like this where a note is inserted,

> This is in the middle of a chapter, and we are at page XYZ. To know more, go look at the note at page UVW.

and text like this in the list of notes, specifically at page UVW,

> (Page XYZ) This is the note

How can I achieve this?

---

The first attempt attempt was to use the `memoir` class (I was using `book`), like this

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\makepagenote
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Some chapter}
\chapter{Some other chapter}
Some text and a page/end note.\pagenote[Page what]{This is an end note}
\backmatter
\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

However,

- I've not understood from the documentation what `what` should be for the it to resolve to the page number where `\pagenote` is used;
- I have to use `memoir` instead of `book`, and I don't see why I should do so for one feature.

Then I discovered that the `pagenote` package exists, so I tried going back to `book` and use this package, like this:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Some chapter}
\chapter{Some other chapter}
Some text and a page/end note.\pagenote{This is an end note}
\backmatter
\printnotes
\end{document}
```

It will generate something like this where the note is set:

> Some text and a page/end note.¹

and this where the notes are printed

> 1. (page 3) This is an end note

Now, I've put the `page` option precisely to avoid the numbering of the notes and just have a reference, where the not is printed, to the page where the note is set (indeed, if I remove `[page]`, `(page 3)` will disappear). However, the `¹` and the `1.` seem to persist. Why is that?

Comment: You can use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` pretty much anywhere, so long as only one target per name.  Unlike `\label` and `\ref`, they go directly into the PDF (`\special`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the `page` option from `pagenote`/`memoir` only adds the page information before the note being printed. If you'd like to remove the note marks and numbering when printed, you have to additionally instruct it to do so. Also, if you'd like to refer to where the note is printed from where it is being set, a traditional cross-reference, with `\label` and `\pageref`, is sufficient.

A couple of alternatives you could use.

With `pagenotes`:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Some chapter}
\chapter{Some other chapter}
Some text and a page/end note.\pagenote{\label{en:1}This is an end note} To
know more see page \pageref{en:1}.
\clearpage
Some text and a page/end note.\pagenote{\label{en:2}This is an end note} To
know more see page \pageref{en:2}.
\backmatter
\printnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Or, with `postnotes` you could also get backlinks from the notes:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{postnotes}
\postnotesetup{
  makemark = {},
  maketextmark = {#2(Page \pnthepage)#3},
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Some chapter}
\chapter{Some other chapter}
Some text and a page/end note.\postnote{\label{en:1}This is an end note} To
know more see page \pageref{en:1}.
\clearpage
Some text and a page/end note.\postnote{\label{en:2}This is an end note} To
know more see page \pageref{en:2}.
\backmatter
\printpostnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

I presume you could also achieve something similar with `enotez`, but I haven't tried.

Comment: I had mistakenly inverted XYZ and UVW in the second part of the initial statement.

Comment: @Enlico That's what I thought. The requirements seemed impossible. :-) I see you fixed it, great.

Comment: By the way, is `\tableofcontents*` meant to be `\tableofcontents`? The asterisk for me just get printed at the end of the index :/

Comment: Yes, indeed, I just got if from you. I'll fix the answer, though.

Comment: Oh, sorry! :D Fixig it there too. Anyway, installed your package. It works well! Should I have any feedback, I'll ask a question here again :)